# VB.Net Make Event through loop was duplicated

Tags: vb.net, events, addhandler

I have a snip code to show how a list of events was created.

```vb
While tb.MoveNext()
    Try
        idMenu = tb.Current.Field(Of Integer)("idMenu")
        menuName = tb.Current.Field(Of String)("HeaderName")
        ClassType = tb.Current?.Field(Of String)("ClassType")
        newTreeItem = New TreeViewItem()

        Dim clickHandler As New MouseButtonEventHandler(Sub(sender, e)
                                                            MessageBox.Show(menuName)
                                                        End Sub)
        AddHandler TryCast(newTreeItem, TreeViewItem).PreviewMouseDoubleClick, clickHandler
     Catch ex As Exception

     End Try
End While
```

In the above code, anything working ok but have a problem is `MessageBox.Show` always shows a fixed value at the last of the while loop.

I can't find out how it works. Can you help me with that!

Comment: Why are you storing elsewhere `newTreeItem` & Co.? These Fields(?) of course store the last item generated in the loop. Have you checked what `sender` is when the event is raised? Why `.TryCast()`? Why not simply in-line the handler in `AddHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are encountering a problem because of how your `Message` is setup in the line:

> ```
> Sub(sender, e)
>     MessageBox.Show(menuName)
> End Sub
> ```

The variable `menuName` is not part of the EventHandler code.

You could try this:

```
Sub(sender, e)
    Dim localMenuName as String = tb.Current.Field(Of String)("HeaderName")
    MessageBox.Show(localMenuName)
End Sub
```

Comment: Your suggestion helps me clearly! I try to put a declaration Dim into a loop and it works.
While tb.MoveNext()
  Dim localMenuName as String = tb.Current.Field(Of String)("HeaderName")
 '''' Call to event '''
End While

Comment: @DevGold Glad to read it works for you. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.